# How come when try to forward engineer my EER model, it doesnt allow me to save an SQL script file?

Tags: mysql, forward-engineer

I am trying to forward engineer my EER Model into a physical database but while trying to do that, it doesn't let me save an SQL script file for it. What should I do? I tried to save it to my local C drive and that doesn't work and also try to save the Script file to my D drive which my USB and that doesn't work. What is causing this simple problem? Here is a screenshot my problem. [Here is the picture link to my MySQL problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDHiE.png)

Comment: Did you really have to post an image of **your entire desktop** to show us the text in that small dialog? Click your Start button and type *Snip* and choose *Snipping Tool*.

Comment: @ Ken White sorry about that. Do you think you could help?